# PF - chart selectItem -> dialog

Tags: primefaces, charts

I'm playing with interactive chart by this topic:

[enter link description here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/interactive.xhtml)

Problem is, that I'm not able to show nothing else than `Growl` component.

The `p:dialog` hasn't been displayed:

```
<p:dialog id="dlg" header="TEST"/>

<p:chart type="bar" model="#{chartView.barModel}" widgetVar="chart">
  <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{chartView.itemSelect}" update="dlg" />
</p:chart>
```

I've also tried (instead of `update` attribute):

- `onComplete="PF('dlg').show();"`
- `onComplete="PF('#form\\:dlg').show();"`
- `onclick="PF('dlg').show();"`
- `onclick="PF('#form\\:dlg').show();"`

How can I show for example `dialog box` with som sub-chart related to selected item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the `dialog` box use something like this.

```
<p:dialog id="basicDialog" widgetVar="dlg" header="TEST" />
```

then call display the `dialog` as.

```
oncomplete="PF('dlg').show();"
```

No need to update the dialog tag.